# Ruby on rails : Create group with many user and one owner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I try to create a groupe system like that : 
- Groupe can have many user
- All users can create a groupe
- But the groupe juste have one owner who can invite other users in the groupe.

At the moment I juste have this logic :

```
class Groupe
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users
end

class Membership
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
end

class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  has_many :memberships
  has_many :projects
end
```

when I look my DB (mongo) I don't see the user_id who create the groupe, and I want to, and I want that this user who create the groupe become the owner and can invite other users.

Does someone know how to implement this ?

Comment: One user has many groupes ?

Comment: One user can create many groupes, and a groupe can have many users

Comment: So we can say that users and groupes, they have `n to n` relationship. There are something missing : Model `UserGroupe` and Table `users_groupes` ? A column `is_owner` (boolean) in the table `users_groupes` should be needed ?

Comment: I need to create an other model UserGroupe ? why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each group has one owner, then you may define a new relationship between group and user like this,

```
class Group
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  has_many :users
  has_one :owner, class_name: 'User'
end

class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  belongs_to :group    
end
```

When a new group is created, its owner is not set yet.

```
 g = Group.create
=> #<Group _id: 58fd7f26476bf77e8f52c349, >
 g.owner
=> nil
```

then set the owner to a user, maybe current user in your case. I just create one for this demo. The benefit of this assignment is that group ownership can be transferred to another person in the future.

```
 owner = g.users.create
=> #<User _id: 58fd7f47476bf77e8f52c34a, group_id: BSON::ObjectId('58fd7f26476bf77e8f52c349')>
 g.owner = owner
=> #<User _id: 58fd7f47476bf77e8f52c34a, group_id: BSON::ObjectId('58fd7f26476bf77e8f52c349')>
```

add more users to this group

```
 g.users.create
=> #<User _id: 58fd7fd4476bf77e8f52c34b, group_id: BSON::ObjectId('58fd7f26476bf77e8f52c349')>
 g.users
=> [#<User _id: 58fd7f47476bf77e8f52c34a, group_id: BSON::ObjectId('58fd7f26476bf77e8f52c349')>, #<User _id: 58fd7fd4476bf77e8f52c34b, group_id: BSON::ObjectId('58fd7f26476bf77e8f52c349')>]
```

Now the group got two users.

Comment: This is a great answer, and I don't know about MongoId, but if you are trying to do this with a SQL db, you're going to need to make a `owner_id` attribute on the group for this to work.